# urllib2 cannot sent GET request

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a python script to control the water boiler in my house from a web site. I have a web page running that will update a text file on my server with 0 or 1 depending on the button on/off selection on the web site. The Python script below can read this all ok and turns on an LED depending on the value of the text file.
I wanted the script to wait when turned on then send the GET URL to my web site to update the text file and turn off the LED. This part is not working. 
I could do this on the web site but would like to know how to send the GET request from the python script for future improvements. I am new to python so any help would be much appreciated.

```js
import urllib2
import wiringpi2
import time

##URL set up URL 1 reads test file on server url2 upload GET/URL tell server to turn water off
url = "http://mywebsite.com/watercontrol.txt"
url2 = "http://mywebsite.com/waterpage,php?status=0"

wiringpi2.wiringPiSetupGpio()
wiringpi2.pinMode(17,1)  ##boiler control

def delay ():
 time.sleep(1)
 readWeb()
 time.sleep(1)
 readWeb()
 urllib2.urlopen(url2).read()
def waterOn ():
 wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,1)
 delay()
def waterOFF ():
 wiringpi2.digitalWrite(17,0)
def readWeb ():
 relaystatus = urllib2.urlopen(url).read(1)
 if relaystatus == "1"
  waterOn()
 elif relaystatus == "0"
  waterOFF ()
 time.sleep(2)
while 1:
 readWeb()
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. calling the readWeb() in the delay caused a loop back to the onWater then back to delay. This caused me to be stuck in a loop.
I have changed this and it works